# Changing the List<int[]> into the Map<int[],int[]> using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

suppose I have a

```
List<int[]> input = ( {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, 
                {1,2,7}, {1,3,1}, {2,2}, 
                {1,2,8}, {1,3,4}, {2,3})
```

and I need to convert it into

```
Map<int[] , int[]> result = { [{1,2} -> {3,4,7,8}] ,
                    [{1,3} -> {1,4}] , 
                    [{2} -> {2,3}]   }
```

Effectively the key for map will be the common values till array length-2 and value should contain the last elements of all those arrays.

Can someone suggest me how to get it using java streams, because in normal loops and all it is real complex thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it's a very bad idea to use the arrays as `Map` keys, because their `hashCode` and `equals` methods are based on object identity, not on the array content. I'd suggest to put the input data into `List<List<Integer>>` instead:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(1,2,4),
        Arrays.asList(1,2,7),Arrays.asList(1,3,1),Arrays.asList(2,2),
        Arrays.asList(1,2,8),Arrays.asList(1,3,4),Arrays.asList(2,3));
```

Having this your task can be solved pretty easily with the cascaded [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> result = lists.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(list -> list.subList(0, list.size() - 1),
            Collectors.mapping(list -> list.get(list.size() - 1),
                Collectors.toList())));
```

The elements are classified by the list prefix (all elements except the last one), then during the downstream reduction the last list elements are extracted and collected to the list.

The result:

```
System.out.println(result);

{[2]=[2, 3], [1, 2]=[3, 4, 7, 8], [1, 3]=[1, 4]}
```

Comment: Suggestion: I think your code would be easier to read if you indented nested collectors more than outer one. That is, if `Collectors.groupingBy(...` is indented 8 spaces, then `Collectors.mapping(...` should be indented 12 spaces and `Collectors.toList()` 16 spaces.